# NodeJS Interactive Twitter Bot Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Hello all I am trying to create an interactive Twitter bot that can fetch and post tweets at the users demand. Here is the code I have written thus far...

```
console.log("The bot is starting...");
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config')
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.start()

var T = new Twit(config);

console.log("Bot is ready to roll!");
var tweet_terms = "";
var tweet_count = 0;
var tweet_command = 0;

console.log("Choose a command...\n1. Get tweets \n2. Post tweet");
prompt.get(['command'], function(err, result) {
    tweet_command = result.command
    if (tweet_command == 1) {
        console.log("You've chosen to get tweets.");
        console.log("Enter in terms you want to search for seperated by commas, \
        \nand also enter in the amount of tweets you want to receive back.");
        prompt.get(['terms', 'count'], function(err, result) {
            tweet_terms = result.terms;
            tweet_count = result.count;
        });
    }
});

var params = {
    q: tweet_terms,
    count: tweet_count
}

T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);

function gotData(err, data, response) {
    var tweets = data.statuses;
    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        console.log(tweets[i].text);
    }
}
```

I am trying to ask the user for input on what terms to search and how many tweets to gather. However my program is stopping before even the user input is prompted. Here is how the program is executing..

`The bot is starting...
Bot is ready to roll!
Choose a command...
1. Get tweets
2. Post tweet
prompt: command:  C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\MERN Tutorials\Twit Twitter Bot\bot.js:42
    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {`

It looks like my gotData function is causing the issue but I don't understand exactly why my program is executing in this fashion.. My prompt isn't even allowing for user input.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at gotData (C:\Users\X\Desktop\MERN Tutorials\Twit Twitter Bot\bot.js:42:31)`

I do not understand why this function is even being called before the user input is handled.. I am new to NodeJS and am very confused why it is acting this way.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);
```

is being called *immediately* after the application runs. After it's complete, you run a bunch of `console.log()` that appears to be providing the responses to the prompt. You wouldn't want to run this until *after* the user has input their choices (otherwise how could you know the params?).

Move the `get` call *inside* the callback of your last prompt:

```
prompt.get(['command'], function(err, result) {
    tweet_command = result.command
    if (tweet_command == 1) {
        console.log("You've chosen to get tweets.");
        console.log("Enter in terms you want to search for seperated by commas, \
        \nand also enter in the amount of tweets you want to receive back.");
        prompt.get(['terms', 'count'], function(err, result) {
            tweet_terms = result.terms;
            tweet_count = result.count;
            T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);
            // ^ here!
        });
    } else {
        // post a tweet code goes here
    }
});
```

Now, while this works, it's not particularly flexible. You could probably rewrite this whole thing a little cleaner so that you can retrieve all the inputs from the user and then pass them as params to a single handler function.

Comment: This allowed for user input however the same error still is being thrown immediately after input now.

Comment: What's the value of `data`? `response`? It's pretty self-explanatory: `data.statuses` is undefined.